# Code optimization for pythagoras theorem

Tags: java, math, methods

could anyone help me with the following code :

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pitagor {
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.println(pitagor(in1(),in2()));

}
public static int in1 (){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Eingabe von a  ");
    int a = input.nextInt();

    return a;
}
public static int in2 (){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Eingabe von b");
    int b = input.nextInt();

    return b;
}
public static double pitagor (int x , int y){
    double c = Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
    return c;
}
}
```

My goal here is to make the code simpler by using separate methods for input and calculation, but i can't seem to understand how to make only one input method instead of *in1()* and *in2()*.

What i tried was :

```
public static void in (){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Eingabe von a  ");
int a = input.nextInt();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Eingabe von b");
int b = input.nextInt(); }
```

but i don't know how to get *a* and *b* from this method, so i can use them in

> pitagor (int x , int y)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can make them (instance) fields.

Comment: Have the `in()` method return an array of size 2? Bit gnarly, but it'd work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pitagor {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println(pitagor(getIntInput("Eingabe von a  "),getIntInput("Eingabe von b")));

    }
    public static int getIntInput(String prompt){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(prompt);
        return input.nextInt();
    }
    public static double pitagor (int x , int y){
        double c = Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
        return c;
    }
}
```